# Are those cardinals not weakly inaccessible?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Consider the set of aleph fixed points, $\{\gamma:\gamma=\aleph_\gamma\}$ and call $\daleth_\alpha$ the $\alpha$-th element of that set. Consider the function $f:\sf Ord\to\sf Ord$ defined by $\alpha\mapsto\daleth_\alpha$, this is the first [Veblen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function) associated with the function $\alpha\mapsto\aleph_\alpha$ and as such it is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_function), so it has a [proper class of fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_lemma_for_normal_functions).

Exercise 1.13.17 of Kunen's "The Foundations of Mathematics" asks to prove that if $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible then it is a fixed point of $f$ and clearly the assertion "$\kappa$ is a fixed point of $f$ $\implies$ $\kappa$ is inaccessible" is not provable in $\sf ZFC$.

Is its negation provable in $\sf ZFC$? More generally is it possible that $\sf ZFC$ proves the existence of a certain cardinal but can't show that it isn't inaccessible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your specific question is: ZFC proves, for instance, that the first fixed point of the $\aleph$ function is **not** weakly inaccessible; this is because that first fixed point has cofinality $\omega$, and so is not regular. Indeed, the $\alpha$th fixed point (call it $\kappa_\alpha$) won't be inaccessible unless $\kappa_\alpha=\alpha$ (since otherwise it won't be regular).

And in fact $\kappa_\alpha=\alpha$ **still** doesn't guarantee inaccessibility; this is because the function $\alpha\rightarrow\kappa_\alpha$ is continuous, and so just as above its first fixed point has cofinality $\omega$, hence isn't regular, hence isn't weakly inaccessible.

The problem, as you can see, is **cofinality**: any construction of an ordinal in terms of fixed points or similar won't be able to get away from this problem on its own.

---

Meanwhile, your broader question - "is it possible that ZFC proves the existence of a certain cardinal but can't show that it isn't inaccessible?" - has a positive answer, but for silly reasons: consider the cardinal $\kappa$ defined to be $0$ if no inaccessibles exist, and the least inaccessible if there is an inaccessible at all. ZFC can't prove "$\kappa$ is not inaccessible" unless ZFC already proves "there are no inaccessible cardinals."

Now, presumably this isn't what you mean, but improving this question in a precise way is quite difficult. Broadly speaking, though, I would say that the following is a good heuristic: for the reasons above, no "concrete" construction which ZFC proves actually builds something can ever have the first thing it builds be inaccessible. And even more broadly, if there is a natural class of ordinals which ZFC proves is nonempty, then ZFC probably proves that the least element of this class isn't inaccessible.

EDIT: The above merely shows that in general, questions of this type are difficult to make precise. *This specific one*, however, has a natural positive solution: it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a regular limit cardinal, that is, weakly inaccessible. And of course it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}$ *isn't* weakly inaccessible.

The proof that $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be weakly inaccessible is quite hard - the relevant technique is [**forcing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)), which roughly speaking lets us enlarge a given model of ZFC by adding new sets in a controlled way. I can't try to explain this here (although you might be interested in  [this introduction by Timothy Chow](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1320)), but let me say some words which, if you choose to dive into forcing, will help outline the path to this result:

In this case, the most natural approach is the following: we start with some beginning model $M$ with a weakly inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ satisfying CH. Now we want, intuitively, to "add $\kappa$-many reals" to $M$. This much is easy to do via forcing; however, there are now two things that need to be checked in the bigger model:

- $2^{\aleph_0}=\vert\kappa\vert$ (that is, we didn't add *more than* $\kappa$-many reals, in the process of adding at least $\kappa$-many reals);
- $\kappa$ remains inaccessible (e.g. amongst the various things forcing can add are bijections between $\kappa$ and smaller ordinals, so after forcing $\kappa$ might not even be a cardinal at all!).

These requirements are addressed by studying the combinatorics of both $\kappa$ itself and of the forcing poset used: the key facts being the regularity of $\kappa$ and the fact that our poset has a combinatorial property called the "countable chain condition."

Comment: Note that this is mirrored to a certain extent on a smaller scale when we try to build up to $\omega_1$ using countable ordinals; and some discussion of this topic can be found [at this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496248/best-known-upper-and-lower-bounds-for-omega-1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so every fixed point of $\alpha\mapsto\kappa_\alpha$ which can be shown to be least fixed point above some ordinal can't be inaccessible because of the same cofinality problem, right?

Comment: Concerning my broader question I discovered after posting this question (thanks to one that was suggested as [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961930/if-2-aleph-0-is-weakly-inaccessible-can-every-cardinal-kappa-in-the-int)) that it is consistent with $\sf ZFC$ that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is weakly inaccessible, although because of reasons I don't understand. Your example while being arguably sillier is definitely simpler

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Yes, your first comment is correct. And re: your second comment, that is indeed a better example - the point I wanted to make, though, is that questions of this form are inherently difficult to make precise. (That said, the example of $2^{\aleph_0}$ gives a natural positive answer, so *this particular* instance should be considered fully addressed. You mention that you don't understand how it can be weakly inaccessible; I've added a bit of explanation in my answer.)

Comment: thanks for the added explanation, it makes a lot of sense intuitively! I'm currently self studying Kunen's book(s) with the objective of understanding forcing so hopefully I'll return to it in the future

Comment: To the proposer: "$ZFC+\exists$ an inaccessible (strong or weak)" is equiconsistent with "ZFC+$2^{\omega}$ is weakly inaccessible.".... $Con ([ZFC])$ is a theorem of "$ZFC+\exists$ an inaccessible", where $[ZFC]$ is an arithmetic coding of $ZFC,$ so by Godel's first incompleteness theorem, if $ZFC$ is consistent then "$\exists$ an inaccessible" cannot be a theorem of $ZFC,$